# How to fix errors when migrating Appengine app from old Google Plugin into Google Tools.?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-datastore

3-4 years ago, I built an Appengine app using datastore technique. At that time, we use Google Plugin. My app was perfect, I was able to deploy it without any problems.

Now, I modified it but couldn't deploy it. Someone told me to migrate it to Google tools. Here is [the guide link](https://cloud.google.com/eclipse/docs/migrating-gpe#app_engine_standard)

I used new eclipse (Oxygen) & installed Cloud Tools for Eclipse. Now after converting my old project to App Engine Project. I got some errors:

-**1ST ERROR**

```
cvc-complex-type.4: Attribute 'autoGenerate' must appear on element 'datastore-indexes'.
```

in **datastore-indexes-auto.xml** file in war\WEBG-INF\appengine-generated

```
  <!-- Indices written at Fri, 17 Aug 2018 19:43:56 ICT -->

**red mark here**   <datastore-indexes> 
    <!-- Used 1 time in query history -->
    <datastore-index kind="Conversation" ancestor="true" source="auto">
        <property name="LessonType" direction="asc"/>
        <property name="LessonNo" direction="asc"/>
    </datastore-index>

    <!-- Used 1 time in query history -->
    <datastore-index kind="Conversation" ancestor="true" source="auto">
        <property name="LessonType" direction="asc"/>
        <property name="ConversationNo" direction="asc"/>
        <property name="LessonNo" direction="asc"/>
    </datastore-index>

    <!-- Used 1 time in query history -->
    <datastore-index kind="Conversation" ancestor="true" source="auto">
        <property name="ConversationNo" direction="asc"/>
        <property name="LessonNo" direction="asc"/>
        <property name="LessonType" direction="asc"/>
        <property name="OrderNo" direction="asc"/>
    </datastore-index>

</datastore-indexes>
```

-**2nd ERROR**

```
Referenced file contains errors (http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jdo/jdoconfig). For more information, right click on the message in the Problems View and select "Show Details..."
```

in **jdoconfig.xml** file in src/META-INF/

```
**red mark here** <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
**red mark here** <jdoconfig xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jdo/jdoconfig"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
**red mark here**   xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jdo/jdoconfig">

   <persistence-manager-factory name="transactions-optional">
       <property name="javax.jdo.PersistenceManagerFactoryClass"
           value="org.datanucleus.api.jdo.JDOPersistenceManagerFactory"/>
       <property name="javax.jdo.option.ConnectionURL" value="appengine"/>
       <property name="javax.jdo.option.NontransactionalRead" value="true"/>
       <property name="javax.jdo.option.NontransactionalWrite" value="true"/>
       <property name="javax.jdo.option.RetainValues" value="true"/>
       <property name="datanucleus.appengine.autoCreateDatastoreTxns" value="true"/>
       <property name="datanucleus.appengine.singletonPMFForName" value="true"/>
   </persistence-manager-factory>
</jdoconfig>
```

My project was perfect on old Google Plugin, but why do we got the errors after migration.

**How to fix it?**

Answer (score 5):

I fixed it

change `<datastore-indexes>` to `<datastore-indexes autoGenerate="true">`

and change

```
<jdoconfig xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jdo/jdoconfig"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jdo/jdoconfig">
```

to

```
<jdoconfig xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jdo/jdoconfig"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jdo/jdoconfig http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jdo/jdoconfig_3_0.xsd">
```

would fix the problem & I was able to deploy it